# Como centralizar verticalmente elementos de um menu

Tags: css, html5

Normalmente coloco position: absolute/relative (dependendo), tranformY(50%) e top: -50%, porém, conforme vou adicionando mais elementos essa artimanha começa a falhar. Gostaria de um resultado como o da imagem. Quais os outros artifícios que vocês costumam usar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display flex no container com align-items: center

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

ou, se vc precisa de mais cross-browser, display inline-block nos childrens com vertical-align: middle

```
 .children {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```